# Getting the size of child database In FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

Does fauna have any function to know the size of the child database.
I want to display the usage size of my database in fauna. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no FQL function to acquire a database's size.

However, the Dashboard does prevent size metrics for child databases. From the Dashboard "Home" page, click on a database that contains child databases, and you'll see in the lower metrics panel a list of child databases and their storage usage.